# PowerPoint macro to insert a picture into a frame

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint file with a content placeholder frame named "image2" on slide 22. There is an image called hello.png in a folder somewhere on my computer. Now I need a macro to put the image into this frame. It is important that the image is having the size and the position of the frame after it is imported.

I found this piece of code on the internet but it doesn't work for me.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(22).Shapes("image2").Picture = LoadPicture("path to the image")
```

It says method or data member not found. I also found the method addPicture but it doesn't work either.

Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it important that the picture be *in* the frame, or is it sufficient that it be added to the slide in the same position and at the same size as the frame?   Is the picture already in the same proportions as the frame?

Comment: Yes, it is important that the picture is in the frame. It should be scaled to the frame of the placeholder.

Comment: Is there some reason why the picture MUST be in a placeholder rather than simply scaled to fit a particular area?

Answer (score 2):

try the following code:

```
Public Sub InsertPic()
    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="d:\pic.jpg", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=200
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this code only adds a picture to the slide. I would like to put a placeholder on a slide and insert an image into this frame with a macro.